# Getting "Zend Guard Run-time support missing!" while running php code

Tags: php, xampp, zend-guard

I installed XAMPP v3.2.2 and PHP Version 7.1.7

I have a php file as newcode1.php in C:/xampp/htdocs folder.

I opened chrome and entered the URL as http://localhost/newcode1.php, tried to run the php code then I got the page saying

**Zend Guard Run-time support missing!**

Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Verify the steps performed to *"Download, install and configure Zend Guard Loader for PHP 5.6"* as described in the CA SAM upgrade guide
[(https://support.ca.com/phpdocs/7/8572/CA_SAM_Rel4_Upgrade_Manual.pdf)](https://profile.ca.com/us/register/login.aspx?TYPE=33554433&REALMOID=06-e81fc501-5d1d-4a33-b51f-22ee9acac391&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=-SM-J%2bg6zoRqC%2f%2funOni5QmU4NoqpA4AmQswggRAWpB1t7RyxGbbxxMyPOu3yJFaH%2bH8&TARGET=-SM-HTTPS%3a%2f%2fsupport%2eca%2ecom%2fredirectform%2fredirect%2ehtml%3foriginaltarget%3dSFRUUFM6Ly9zdXBwb3J0LmNhLmNvbS9waHBkb2NzLzcvODU3Mi9DQV9TQU1fUmVsNF9VcGdyYWRlX01hbnVhbC5wZGY%2faW50Y21wPXNlYXJjaHJlc3VsdGNsaWNrJnJlc3VsdG51bT0y)

Verify steps:

- Download Zend Guard Loader for PHP 5.6 (you may have to register with Zend to download - http://www.zend.com/en/products/loader/downloads#Windows)
- Add ZendLoader.dll from zip file to php extensions directory (c:\Program Files (x86)\ca\Sam\env\php\ext)
- Add the following lines to php.ini (c:\Program Files (x86)\ca\Sam\env\php\php.ini):

[Zend]

zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\ca\Sam\env\php\ext\ZendLoader.dll"

zend_loader.enable=1

zend_loader.disable_licensing=0

-Make sure the PATH environment variable contains an entry to PHP.exe  e.g. \Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6;

-Verify PHP by running PHP.exe -v from the command line. It should return the following.

C:\Users\Administrator>php -v

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Comment: this was the guide from the official zend site , you're missing something for sure @Sayeed

Comment: Thanks for your response Ahmad. •Add ZendLoader.dll from zip file to php extensions directory (c:\Program Files (x86)\ca\Sam\env\php\ext).  I don't have ca folder in Program Files (x86).

Comment: Your Welcome @Sayeed, hope your problem is solved quickly

Comment: check [Zend Guard Run-time support missing](http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/Web-Hosting/Zend-Guard/Run-time-support-missing)

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to help you with this specific issue but I can say that php 7.1 will not work with zend loader because it's supported only up to v5.6. Please downgrade yout php to 5.6 and make sure that the build is nts (non thread safe) because thread safe will not work..
Although you have to run the php in fastcgi mode because all xampps come up with thread safe php